# Can I save all my data in one firebase database child?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have a very specific app and I don't know how should I save all my data in the Firebase database. Is it ok if I'll save all my data in one child and then simply get the first 0-1000 childs, then 1000-2000, 2000-3000 and so on. Will it affect performance?

Comment: I've seen it both improve performance to combine some datas into a single string value, as hurt performance when taken too far. It's impossible to give performance disclaimers without seeing a concrete example of the data you're storing.

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows how to build and commit a batch of writes in Android:

```
// Get a new write batch
WriteBatch batch = db.batch();

// Set the value of 'NYC'
DocumentReference nycRef = db.collection("cities").document("NYC");
batch.set(nycRef, new City());

// Update the population of 'SF'
DocumentReference sfRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
batch.update(sfRef, "population", 1000000L);

// Delete the city 'LA'
DocumentReference laRef = db.collection("cities").document("LA");
batch.delete(laRef);

// Commit the batch
batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        // ...
    }
});
```